# Impossible to add new content

Tags: 7, files, media

I migrated my web to webhosting. There is a problem when I want to add new content, it's not able to add new content with images or files. Do you know where to look to solve it? Does it relate to access rights to directories where Drupal stores those files or is it something else?

When I want to upload an image, it writes:

- Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to access public://image.jpg in file_save_upload() (line 1528 of /web/www/x.y.com/includes/file.inc).
- File upload error. Could not move uploaded file.

thank you

Comment: review permissions in the /sites/all/files directory. also review the owner.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Can't believe this question is closed for being "too localized!" That's silly.

Comment: For me, the issue was PHP has SAFE_MODE set to ON. I cannot change this easily with my host. So following [the instructions here](http://drupal.org/node/1099160) worked. Basically, you modify line 1528 of includes/file.inc to the following: `if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$source], drupal_realpath($file->uri))) {` of course, the better solution is to turn off safe mode, if you can.

Answer (score 1):

review permissions in the /sites/all/files directory. you can **test** inside **files** directory, changing permissions to test the correct permissions. for example you, for test, can change to 755 in recursive mode: `chmod 755 files/ -R`. also review the owner of directory. According my experience, the owner can be a cause.

(According I remember, permission 777 number is the most higher number, but not is recommended).

Comment: I prefer to use chown than chmod :-)

Comment: I don't have `sites/all/files` directory. It was working without it on localhost.

Comment: I changed the permissions of `sites/default/files` recursively to 755 but this didn't help. When I want to add image it writes something like `unable to load file`

Comment: I edited the question and set permissions to 777.

Comment: well, seems that could be related with the tmp directory http://drupal.org/node/84405#comment-872211. I suggest update the tmp path in your Drupal, and review the permissions of this new tmp directory.

Answer (score -1):

Please define "it's not able to add new content with images or files" ? was the content save failed or only the image failed to attach ? I suggest you check Drupal status report.

Comment: this should be a comment. it's not an answer.

Comment: @Sivaji The content save failed.

Comment: Checking Drupal status report will probably reveal the cause (and fix) most of the time. It is worth to be an answer, IMO.